# Missing JNDI entry

Tags: java, jndi, netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1

I recently made a simple Java EE program in NetBeans 8.1 and pushed the code to a remote repository. Now, I've pulled that code down onto another computer and my application fails to run with the error `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: App-ejb`.

Using asadmin on the computer on which my app is working, I can see the JNDI entry just fine by running `asadmin list-jndi-entries --context java:global`. However, I can't find the JNDI entry for App-ejb in any namespace on the computer on which my app is not working.

How should I debug from here?

Answer (score 0):

To solve, I cleaned and re-built App-ejb and then deployed it again to Glassfish. (`Clean and build` and `Deploy` are options when right clicking on the module in NetBeans.)